# Adding Segment controller to place that already has one

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, rightbarbuttonitem

I have  menu button that is being put in the Navigation controller on every page in the rightBarButtonItem (customer wishes) from a my BaseViewController (all other classes inherit from this).

I want to add a segment controller next to the menu button on one of the pages.

Is there a way to just add a segment controller next to it without replacing one or the other?

I have seen examples of adding 2 items into one controller, but I need to add them at separate times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a view that contains the menu button and the segmented button and then create a UIBarButtonItem using initWithCustomView:(UIView  *)customView and pass the view with the buttons.  Then set rightBarButtonItem to this barButtonItem.

Comment: Is there a way to get a the current rightBarButtonItem (the current button) and then add that to a new view with my new segment control?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Note that the rightBarButtonItem is of type BarButtonItem which is not a subclass of UIView.