# how to add custom right bar button on MPMoviePlayerContoller view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I tried this,

```
self.navigationItem.righBarButton = customView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the spare description what you exactly want to achieve in respect to MPMoviePlayerController, I take your question simply as referring to the general "How do I add a custom view as rightBarButtonItem?".

The answer is, you simply have to create a UIBarButtonItem with your custom view and assign the result as rightBarButtonItem like this:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView]];
```

A similar question was also already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630800/adding-segment-controller-to-place-that-already-has-one?rq=1) for example.